# Why does ruby return the value of an object instead of the whole object?

Tags: ruby, object

just for exercise I implemented a queue class with ruby. The elements in the queue are nodes, which are implemented in another class. These nodes hold a certain value and can also hold information on their successor when added to the queue. The node class looks as follows:

```
class Node
attr_accessor :value, :successor

def initialize(value)
    @value     = value
    @successor = nil
end

def set_successor(successor)
    @successor = successor
end

def get_successor()
    @successor
end

def get_value()
    @value
end

def to_s()
    @value.to_s
end
end
```

After creating objects, such as `object1 = Node.new(12)` and `object2 = Node.new("Foo")`, I can use the `get_value` method to obtain the objects values, which is exactly what the method is supposed to do.

```
puts object1.get_value
==> 12
puts object2.get_value
==> Foo
```

Yet, when just using `puts object1` or `puts object2`, still the objects values, 12 and Foo are
displayed. Here, I would expect a more cryptic message, telling me that this is an object of the class node, which is what the objects are.

```
puts object1.class
==> Node
```

So, does anybody know a hint, why the objects value is displayed, when actually the whole object is supposed to be shown?

Comment: Try `p object1` and you'll get what you expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`puts` calls the `to_s` method on objects before printing them](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fd444f90b5ec99c8081222d91a6e8d172e617bb9/io.c#L7090). You have defined `to_s` in your class to call `to_s` of the `@value`. Therefore, instances of your class have the same string representation as the value they hold.

If you would write

```
class Node
  # ...

  def to_s
    "Node<#{@value.to_s}>"
  end
end
```

You would get

```
node = Node.new(42)
puts node
# Node<42>
```

As a side note: your Ruby code is not very idiomatic, here are some observations:

- omit the empty parentheses `()`
- no need to write getters and setters, that's what `attr_accessor` is for
- instance variables are automatically set to `nil`
- outside of the constructor, better use the getter `value` instead of instance var `@value`
- malformed indentation

Here's an equivalent implementation:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :successor

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    value.to_s
  end
end
```

In action:

```
node = Node.new(42)
node.value = 123

succ = Node.new(124)
node.successor = succ

puts node
# 123

puts node.successor
# 124
```

In case you didn't want a setter for `value`, use `attr_reader` instead of `attr_accessor`.